# Remove organisation chart from MySite

Tags: mysite, organization-browser

We want to delete the Org chart from mysite, how do I get rid of it?

I have seen plenty of posts where clients want it added or fixed, but nothing about how to delete it entirely.

Comment: what is version of sharepoint 2010 or 2013?

Comment: sharepoint 2013

Comment: But in 2013 it is not added by default. if someone want, he need to add it manually.

Comment: the Org chart is a web part in the organizationview.aspx page, you can remove this page from navigation menu in the site settings or you can remove the web part from the page with SharePoint Deisgner

Answer (score 1):

1. Using SharePoint Designer, open the root of the site where OrganizationView.aspx is found in your installation of SharePoint. (For example: where http://xx.xx.com/OrganizationView.aspx is the location, open http://xx.xx.com).
2. From the left menu, Click All Files.
3. Open organizationview.aspx.
4. Comment out the div section with HTML comment code:
   `<!--<div class="orgBrowser">
   </div>-->`
5. Save.
6. You can put in a customized message in a paragraph tag above the div section, such as: `<p>Customized message goes here.</p>`